# How to retrieve global index while using ddply?

Tags: r, indexing, plyr

I am trying to find the best deal in terms of price/carat from the Diamonds dataset from the **plyr** package

So I do

```
    new = ddply(diamonds, c("cut", "color", "clarity"), transform, ecart= price/carat -  mean(price/carat))   
    best = ddply(new, c("cut", "color", "clarity"), summarize, which(ecart == min(ecart))
```

But when I do that I get

```
    head(best)
    cut color clarity ..1  
    1 Fair     D      I1   4  
    2 Fair     D     SI2  49  
    3 Fair     D     SI1  39  
    4 Fair     D     VS2   9  
    5 Fair     D     VS1   2
```

So the index seem to be takend from the subgroups being made by ddply.
Here only the first index, 4, correspond to the global index.
if I look up new[2,] it is not of the type Fair, D, VS1 for instance.

Any idea on how I can retrieve the global index position easily?

How would you for instance, add a id column elegantly?
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to the identify diamond with the lowest value of `ecart` for each unique combination of `cut`, `color` and `clarity`, then maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
new <- ddply(diamonds, c("cut", "color", "clarity"), transform, 
         ecart= price/carat -  mean(price/carat))   
best <- ddply(new, c("cut", "color", "clarity"), 
         .fun = function(x){x[which.min(x$ecart),]})
```

which doesn't require messing about with indices outside of each piece of `diamonds` passed to `.fun`.

**EDIT**

Hadley points out in the comments that

```
ddply(new, c("cut","color","clarity"), subset, ecart == min(ecart))
```

is more elegant. It will also correctly pull out all rows that fit the condition in the case of ties for the minimum.

Comment: doh - should have hit refresh before submitting, nice work +1

Comment: I was hesitant to ask for the way to get the id row as an extra, so your answer was not in vain ;) thank you guys for the clarifications.

Comment: You can do the last bit a little more elegantly with subset: `ddply(new, c("cut", "color", "clarity"), subset, ecart == min(ecart))`

Comment: Not only is @hadley's suggestion more elegant, but it is also arguably more correct, since it will correctly return any and all rows that are tied for the minimum, whereas `which.min` will just pull out the first instance it finds.

Comment: awesome. you all rock. ps : might as well include that example into http://had.co.nz/stat405/resources/drills/plyr.html

Comment: I would add for future newbies like me : ddply(new, .(cut, color, clarity), subset, ecart == min(ecart)) would also work as .(xxx, yyy) is the  way plyr does c("xxx", "yyy") and it is more elegant without the quotes

Answer (score 2):

I think I understood what you wanted properly. You can use the `which.min` function directly to index into the data.frames that are being returned by ddply. You just need to use an anonymous function to do so:

```
ddply(new, c("cut", "color", "clarity"), function(x) x[which.min(x$ecart) ,])
```

As for your second question, you could generate an ID column like this:

```
diamonds$id <- seq_len(nrow(diamonds))
```

though I'm not sure how that ties into the problem?